# Class rank in Battlefield 1, is it per operation?

Tags: battlefield-1

We played Battlefield 1 on monday in a group and I noticed that my medic class got to about midway between rank 0 and 1 up in the left corner during one operation.

The operation ended and we started a new one and I noticed that my rank progress was reset, no progress between 0 and 1.

So my question is:

1. Is class rank (for medic as an example) per operation? So that if I don't earn rank 1 during one operation I need to start over on the next?
2. per map or area? (ie. the desert area, since we have different character models and looks, is the rank I earn here only for this "character"?)
3. per side? ie. whatever progress I get on the german medic class doesn't copy over to the allied side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that your progress glitched out.

It is supposed to keep the xp/progress towards your next rank, that's how it has been for me (scout rank 8)

I'd suggest trying to play a short game of domination tdm or something and check if your progress towards class rank saves at all.

if not i'd suggest contacting support